# Remove Search icon from the Search Bar:Winrt

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

The Search Bar in Windows 8.1 has a default search icon attached to it .

Like This

[image]

Is there any way i can get rid of that icon ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit style of SearchBox to remove search button.

**To get style of SearchBox follow below steps**

Step 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JI2e.png

Step 2 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJabd.png and Press Ok

Step 3 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/V88rs.png

```
 <Style x:Key="SearchBoxStyle1" TargetType="SearchBox">
        ..........................
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="SearchBox">
                    ......
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" InputScope="Search" MinHeight="{ThemeResource SearchBoxTextBoxThemeMinHeight}" MaxLength="2048" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" PlaceholderText="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" Style="{StaticResource SearchTextBoxStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Button x:Name="SearchButton" Height="0" Width="0" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="{ThemeResource SearchBoxButtonThemeFontWeight}" Style="{StaticResource SearchButtonStyle}"/>
                    .......
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

<SearchBox Height="35" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxStyle1}"/>
```